# Trying to update a jQuery 1.4.2 plugin to 1.8.2 but getting Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-plugins

## [RESOLVED]

See below for question details.

The line

```
var maxUl = $(objUl+'[rel="'+maxItems+'"]');
```

needs to be

```
var maxUl = $(objUl.attr('id')+'[rel="'+maxItems+'"]');
```

to be functional with the current jQuery 1.8.2 implementation.

---

First of all thanks for taking the time to look at my issue with me. I've looked through many of the other questions and as best I can tell this issue isn't the same.

I'm getting this error from firebug when I attempt to load a jQuery plugin on the page: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object Object][rel="7"]

*Note:* The plugin works fine when running jQuery 1.4.2, but running multiple jQuery instances isn't an option for this project.

The plugin I'm trying to implement can be found [here](http://www.ajaxshake.com/plugin/EN/828/263cff77/drill-down-menu-with-jquery-drilldownmenu.html) and downloaded [here](http://www.ajaxshake.com/demo/EN/828/263cff77/drill-down-menu-with-jquery-drilldownmenu.html)

### Best Guess

So far I think I've managed to narrow it down to these two lines in his js file (jquery.dcdrilldown.1.2.js)

```
// Get level of largest sub menu
var maxUl = $(objUl+'[rel="'+maxItems+'"]');
var getIndex = findMaxIndex(maxUl);
```

And as best I can tell breaks after calling

```
var maxUl = $(objUl+'[rel="'+maxItems+'"]');
```

Because firebug doesn't make it to the breakpoints in `findMaxIndex()` method.

### My HTML file looks like this

#### JS Call

```
$(function() { // Drill down menu
  $('#drilldown').dcDrilldown({
    speed           : 'slow',
    saveState       : true,
    showCount       : false,
    linkType        : 'breadcrumb'
});
```

#### HTML ul

```
<div class="graphite dd-container">
<ul id="drilldown">
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Products</a>
```

Any help you can offer will be greatly appreciated, thanks everyone.

Comment: Resolved my own error! Turns out it had something to do with the first of the two lines  I noted. The syntax needed to use the .append() function instead of appending with a '+'. Correct line is as such:
        var maxUl = objUl.append('[rel="'+maxItems+'"]');

Comment: Typical causes for this: Your selector didn't match any elements of the DOM,
You are looping through objects using a selector that is not always true, or 
Selector is in the wrong format. Check out: http://www.thalesjacobi.com/Jquery_error_uncaught_exception_Syntax_error_unrecognized_expression

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to look at what objUl is being set to. I bet before it used to resolve itself to a string when you concatenated to another string. Now it probably doesn't do that (hence the [object Object] part).

Look at what objUl is being set to and try to get maybe it's .attr('id') value instead.

**Edit**
Change

```
var maxUl = $(objUl+'[rel="'+maxItems+'"]');
```

to

```
var maxUl = $(objUl.attr('id')+'[rel="'+maxItems+'"]');
```

Comment: Thanks I did manage to do that. It was trying to create a DOM object and was doing it in an old way jQuery didn't like. The objUi element needed to be appended with the .append() function, not the '+' sign. Thanks so much for your answer!

Comment: Just tried to vote you up, sadly I don't have the rep for it yet :( Thanks though!

Comment: Your answer is more correct then my own, though the .append() will work, it adds it as text to the page! Using your .attr() method works perfectly though.

Answer (score 0):

To work with jQuery 1.10.4 the following changes make-it works finee

```
// var maxUl = $(objUl+' [rel="'+maxItems+'"]');
var maxUl = $(objUl.html()+' [rel="'+maxItems+'"]');
```

and

```
//$('#'+idHeader+' a').live('click',function(e){
$('#'+idHeader).on('click','a',function(e){
```